# Are "Hail-Mary" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

For those of you who don't know, a Hail-Mary pass is a maneuver in American Football which is executed late in a losing game, in the desperate hope that a miracle will occur.

[image]

On Stack Overflow, this often takes these forms (this is not a comprehensive list):

1. I have this highly obscure/obsolete product, which I have documentation for the API, but I'm having [specific] problems with it.  Does anyone know why, and how can I fix it?
2. I have this product, which I want to use with this other product, and I read the documentation for both products, but I didn't find the method I'm looking for that frobnosticates the two products together.  Is there a way to do it?
3. I have a well-known product, and I'm trying to do [this] with it, but I can't figure out how [because said company's customer-service sucks, and I think I can get a faster answer here].

Such questions are often accompanied by the phrase "Is it possible?"; their defining characteristic is that they require someone with exactly the knowledge they're looking for, but the likelihood that someone with that exact knowledge wandering in and answering their question is vanishingly small.

Hence the name "Hail-Mary question."  It requires the single person in the stadium audience, who actually knows the answer, to be standing in the end-zone at the precise moment that the ball is thrown.

In the past, we would close such questions as "Too Localized," but that close reason no longer exists, and there was some grousing about how we used to close too many questions as Too Localized.

Are these questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?  If they are not, under what theory do we "on-hold" them?

Comment: Frobnosticates? Let me get my dictionary...

Comment: Would you classify questions about bleeding edge tech as "hail mary"? Personally having answered questions about Microsoft's Windows 8 for the last 8 months, I saw a lot of questions that would fit under your first two bullet points. The tech was just so new that knowledge was scant.

Comment: @chuex: Not necessarily.  If such questions are asked too early, the background knowledge that people have about the technology will eventually catch up.

Comment: Related: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3ykWbu2Gl0

Comment: @RobertHarvey "too localized" means the answer is unlikely to help any future readers.  This is entirely independent from the number of people that can answer the question.  There are plenty of very hard questions that only a handful of people could answer, but that very many people would be helped by reading the answer.

Comment: @Servy: Not to put too fine a point on it, but a question that never gets an answer is useful to nobody.  It's less than useless, because it attracts visitors who have to take the time to process the fact that the question has no answer.  It's an Internet dead end, in other words, like all too many forum posts.

Comment: @Robert Well, yeah, it's not all that useful, because it hasn't been answered yet. That doesn't make the question itself bad. I'm calling out the "less than useless" thing, though: there's no difference here between someone visiting a non-answered question asked yesterday, and a non-answered question asked 10 months ago; both are "internet dead ends' for the time being.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: Erm, except that the one asked ten months ago has been trapping people for... say, about ten months.

Comment: @Robert In what way are they trapped?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: I'll rephrase.  The one that was asked ten months ago has been an Internet dead end for... 10 months.

Comment: @Robert Right, so do we go closing questions that haven't been answered after 10 months?

Comment: I don't actually see anything wrong with this "internet dead end" thing. Person googles the issue, comes here from a result, finds no answer, keeps googling, may still find no answer. That doesn't make the question bad for existing.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Yes, the system already automatically closes (and deletes? don't remember) questions that haven't attracted attention (views/answers/comments) according to some algorithm. I personally think it is too lax, but that may just be me. I seem to remember that the rules were about to be tightened, but not sure if it has happened yet.

Comment: They're not dead ends, they're a way to feel closer to the ancients! http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @RobertHarvey, [coincidence?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey But there are plenty of questions on this site that are hard to answer, and that not many people have the expertise to answer, that *have good answers*.  Quite simply because there are a lot of experts here.  On top of that, the benefit of getting such an answer is much higher than the costs of an unanswered question.  Even if some don't get answers, as long as some do it's very likely we'll see a net positive effect.  And in general I'd just be sad if we said we want to have less hard questions so that we can answer more easy ones.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe I wasn't completely clear about the whole "Hail Mary" thing, but I'm basically talking about questions that have no hope of ever being answered.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, none of your examples are questions that couldn't ever be answers.  They're questions that probably have a lower probability of being answered; they're harder to answer.  That's a far cry from "can't be answered".

Comment: @Servy: Here's a good example of a Hail Mary question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18903358

Comment: I can't believe nobody's mentioned the Tumbleweed badge. I'm pretty sure the entire point of that badge is to 1) provide consolation for common questions that are pushed into obscurity by other circumstances, and 2) reward questions that are obscure due to a lack of experts in their domain, which can often result in low activity in the first week.

Comment: Step aside, I happen to have a PhD in frobnostication from the Glubniversiy of Blargleheim. I'm also the author of [obscure product].

Comment: I sure hope they are on topic here! This question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486752/ooo-uno-java-trackedchanges-how-to-accept-or-hide-tracked-changes-when-doc is so absurdingly bizarre that it took years to get an answer. Athe bless the user who answered it. I would be scared if it had been removed before.

Comment: There's a fourth category of "Hail Mary" questions that should be addressed here as well -- these are questions of the form "I'm trying to frobnosticate an X in a slightly-unusual way, and I'm getting <insert truly bizarre error that almost nobody has seen before>".  While some of these are indeed syntax errors, others expose rejects-valid bugs in compilers -- C++ is an arcane enough language that it's quite possible for otherwise-conforming compilers to disagree about what to accept. (continuing in next comment)

Comment: Other questions of that category are even *more* bizarre, involving embedded toolchains behaving in truly absurd ways, downright bad code generation from compilers, or seemingly impossible behavior during debugging!  Simply saying "these folks shouldn't be asking here because we shouldn't expect anyone to know how to answer the question" is doing a disservice to the asker *and* the community -- I have seen several questions where the SO community's involvement was that last piece that pushed an issue into the "file a bug report" bin.

Comment: Sometimes it can take years for the solution (and a very effective one) to arrive, never say never.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Yes, they're on topic.

> (...) their defining characteristic is that they require someone with exactly the knowledge they're looking for, but the likelihood that someone with that exact knowledge wandering in and answering their question is vanishingly small.

All three examples you listed seem like perfectly valid questions to me. Whether the *expertise exists* to answer it isn't a problem with the question itself: it could be perfectly fine, and the fact a question might require specialist knowledge doesn't make that question bad - it's the reason we're here!

Whether a question might not get answered has *nothing to do* with whether it's a good, on topic question. They simply have *no connection.* It's not a problem with the question itself. It just indicates a missing in our audience's expertise. It's not the question's problem if we don't have someone with the required expertise to answer it (yet).

I don't even see why these would get closed as too localised - that sounds like a terrible misuse of that close vote reason to me.

### How would you close these, anyway?

The identifying criteria for these questions is that they have a small chance of being answered. [Obscurity does not make things off topic here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lolcode)

In light of the fact we can't see the future, the only way to determine whether a question fits this criteria is to wait a few weeks or months. We can't close it right away saying "I don't think this will get answered", since a weird-looking question might get answered the following day by someone who had to go down that weird road a few weeks ago.

This wait-and-see thing would just boil down to this rules change: every question that doesn't get answered within X weeks/months is automatically off topic and close-worthy. That would be silly. Let's not do this.

The fact we can't judge anything about this by the question alone is, to me, the strongest indicator that these questions are fine and there's nothing wrong with them.

Comment: Yep. [My Hail Mary on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/101849/how-do-i-retrieve-basic-information-about-an-afs-mounted-filesystem) eventually bore fruit, too. Though by then I had solved the problem another way.

Comment: _"they have a small chance of being answered"_ -- funny things happen when this chance turns out _fat_. Most of _isitpossible_ questions I've seen quickly catch 10-20 low quality answers pointing to, well, the tool that just makes _itpossible_, proving that these are just tool recommendations behind the smokescreen. Oh and about 99% of these are [insufficient research](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192143/165773) _"oy wey I'm so desperate I googled alot (yeah sure like whole 5 minutes) and couldn't find anything"_

Comment: @gnat This question is not about the _Is it possible?_ category of questions, though - just a category which appears to often intersect with that one. Two of the three examples given in the question aren't _Is it possible?_ questions; Robert just said that the questions he's asking about often are also _Is it possible?_ questions. It isn't the thing being talked about here, and the main problem here aren't questions that ask whether something is possible (that's just a tangential related issue). That's probably worth addressing separately though!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs well, then the question is how do I distinguish these _rare true Hail-Mary_ questions from mountains of crap that contains the same _isitpossible_ cliche? "It walks and quacks" like a duck, now tell me what to look for to find out it's not a duck indeed?

Comment: @gnat Robert's criteria was just obscure questions that have a very small chance of being answered. That's it. I quoted the defining characteristic he provided, and it wasn't that the questions ask if something's possible. What do _Is it possible?_ questions have to do with that? (By contrast it sounds like they get answered plenty, and are problematic for entirely different reasons)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs yeah, in the hindsight it seems easy. But, when it just pops up and there are no answers yet, how do I know about their chance of being answered? Am I expected to wait until it catches 5-10-20 crappy answers there-s-your-tool _before_ casting close vote? Example: [Is it possible to debug the WF used to build in VS2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829574/is-it-possible-to-debug-the-wf-used-to-build-in-vs2012) (23 hours passed, no answers yet)

Comment: @gnat ... I don't know. Like I said, this isn't about is-it-possible questions - at all. Maybe you should create another question about how to respond to those.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs wait a minute... the idea of your answer is one would better abstain of closing these questions, right? Now you tell me you don't know how to distinguish these from much more frequent crappy questions that are indeed close-worthy, right? and your answer doesn't even mention that one may have trouble trying to figure that. But then, how can this answer be useful to close voter / flagger? I mean, the way it is stated now, it just reads as "if you see is-it-possible, just keep it open (...until it picks a solid amount of crappy answers?)"

Comment: @gnat "wait a minute... the idea of your answer is one would better abstain of closing these questions, right?" If by "these questions" you mean "questions which theoretically have a low chance of being answered", yes. If you mean "is it possible? questions", then no, I'm not even acknowledging those in this answer. I put it to you that if you think my answer is addressing is-it-possible questions, or if you think this question is about those, you have misread something. If you expect me to respond to those... _I don't care about them_, this question isn't about those.

Comment: I'm not particularly bothered by "is it possible" questions. Their real question, of course, is "what code do I need to use to accomplish this?"  And we already know how to handle those.

Comment: Sometime such questions get an answer, or even two! Shameless plug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713660/pdf-js-get-the-text-colour